# Django 3.2 CITEXT and unique_together

Tags: django, orm, case-insensitive

I'm using Django 3.2 and postgreSql 12.
I've added a new text field that should be case-insensitive, i.e if the value 'ab' exists, I want the DB to fail the request if someone is inserting 'Ab'. But this field shouldn't be unique all over the table, but unique with another field (unique_together).
I've tried creating the field as ['CITEXT'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields) and since it's deprecated in Django 4.2 I've used the [Collation migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#managing-collations-using-migrations) as recommended.
The migrations passed, and when testing it I see that I can create two objects with the same letters, and different cases. Am I doing something wrong or this implementation of case-insensitive shouldn't work with 'unique_together'?

The collation migration:

```
operations = [
    CreateCollation(
        "case_insensitive",
        provider="icu",
        locale="und-u-ks-level2-kn-true",
        deterministic=True,
    ),
]
```

The model changes:

```
class MyItem(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(db_collation="case_insensitive", db_index=True, max_length=100, null=True)
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, related_name='my_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('identifier', 'container_id')
```

After running the migrations, I've successfully created two MyItems with the same container and identifier='ab' and 'Ab'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it had to be non-deterministic - `deterministic=False`. It basically solved it.

The problem is that it raised another issue with seems to be a bug in Django 3.2, where you can't use this collation with a field that's unique.